Access 2021. Propiedades de tabla. "activar orden" ¿Qué es y para qué sirve? Ni microsoft me responde
En mi access 2021 aparece, como última propiedad de tabla, la propiedad "activar orden", debajo de la propiedad "ordenar al cargar por". Adjunto foto.
Esta propiedad tiene valor 0. Por muchos cambios que haga en las propiedades de tabla, o cambie este valor 0, por -1, 1, etc. No hay cambios en las vista hoja de datos. Además al volver a la propiedad vuelve a tener valor 0.

He preguntado en foros de microsoft, tanto en castellano como inglés, podéis hacer la búsqueda y su resultado será mi pregunta. Nadie de por allí sabe de lo que hablo. Son ustedes, stackoverflow, mi última oportunidad.

Yo tengo el oficce 365 y no me aparece esa propiedad.

Yo tengo 2 instalaciones de access 2021. En una sale y en la otra no. Nadie en Microsoft ha sabido responder. En alguna ocasión hay respuesta, pero lo confunden con "ordenar al cargar" ¿Será una de esas opciones que han quedado obsoletas y en alguna ocasión se manifiesta, pero está como capada, sin cambios en la BD?

La verdad es que no tengo idea de Access, lo he abierto 2 veces en mi vida y una fue para comentarte lo anterior. Si tuviera que adivinar, quizás es una propiedad que se agrega por programación, algún módulo de VB puede estar agregando una propiedad (cosa que ni se si es posible) u algún complemento o pluggin que tengas instalado

https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/msoffice/forum/all/propiedad-de-tabla-en-la-vista-dise%c3%b1o-activar/660e497b-8afd-4b5e-be52-478eee6e1a44
